# Create a new column based on conditional statement of another column R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new column that will return Yes or No based on conditions of another column.

I have tried to use `grepl`, `substr` and `nchar`, `ifelse`. The issue is that the data has characters and numbers in the column that I am trying to condition.

```
(nchar(as.character(expo$BuyerNumber)) == 3)
(substr(as.character(expo$BuyerNumber),1,1 == 6))
```

I want to create a a new column that will have yes or no if the following conditions are met. If the first number starts with 6 and is of length 3 then yes if not then no will be returned.

Examples:

```
610
610B
620C
```

All above would return yes

```
426
62B
21C
```

All above would return no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem, I see, might be that you are comparing substr (which will give a character) to a number. That is likely to give false boolean.
Something like below.

```r
(nchar(as.character(expo$BuyerNumber)) == 3)

(as.integer(substr(as.character(expo$BuyerNumber),1,1)) == 6)
```

If it does not work, please let me know.

Comment: Camille, thank you for spotting this you were right and I got exactly what I needed. Appreciate the prompt response! Up voted answer!